# ckan.plugins.core.PluginNotFoundException: pdf_view Error

Tags: plugins, pdfview

I installed CKAN 2.8.5 from package on Ubuntu 16.04. I activated the ckanext-pdfview. Everything is OK. Bu t when I run paster commands I received the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 1108, in command
    self._load_config()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 330, in _load_config
    self.site_user = load_config(self.options.config, load_site_user)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 237, in load_config
    load_environment(conf.global_conf, conf.local_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 116, in load_environment
    p.load_all()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 140, in load_all
    load(*plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 154, in load
    service = _get_service(plugin)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 257, in _get_service
    raise PluginNotFoundException(plugin_name)
ckan.plugins.core.PluginNotFoundException: pdf_view
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When I entered into the virtual environment I ran the pip command with path. First I found the path with which pip command in the virtual env and then I ran the pip command with path.